# debugging webpack issue --config not found

Tags: node.js, webpack

so my webpack has been working fine. I needed a different structure then the default so I placed the webpack files in a `build` folder. As per documentation I placed the `--config` option in the package json but I am still not able to access the file in the debugger.
Below is my setup:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "local": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.local.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "build_dev": "node build/build.dev.js",
    "build_stg": "node build/build.stg.js",
    "build_prod": "node build/build.prod.js",
  },
```

When I run the command `node-nightly --inspect ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`
I get the error:

```
No configuration file found and no output filename configured via CLI option.
A configuration file could be named 'webpack.config.js' in the current directory.
```

In terms of my file structure I have under the root, a folder named `build` it contains the webpack config files (I was not sure how the structure is written on SO)
Version usage:
`"webpack": "^3.12.0"`
`node 9.3`

Comment: What version of nodejs & of webpack-dev-server? This looks right. An alternative is to put the webpack.config.js in the current folder and have it refer to sub config in the build folder.

Comment: @Andre M added to the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**--config** is a property on webpack. You are trying to set a --config property on webpack-dev-server [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)

You can move your devserver to your webpack.config.js file

```
devServer: {
        inline: true,
        progress: true
}
```

and then refer to your webpack.config.js file directly in npm like so:

```
webpack --config ./build/yourfile.config.js
```

you can give any name you wish to the config file if you are using **--config** property else webpack will always try to find **webpack.config.js** in your projects root directory.

**ELSE**

you can create a *webpack.config.js* in your root and switch between config version on runtime like so:

```
//webpack.config.js
const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

if (TARGET === 'build') {
    module.exports = require('./buildScripts/webpack.config.dev');
}
else if (TARGET === 'build:prod') {
    module.exports = require('./buildScripts/webpack.config.prod');
}
```

and in *package.json* you need the appropriate targets to match *npm_lifecycle_event*.

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --watch",
    "build:prod": "webpack",
  }
```